# what happens to partitions when I reduce a dynamo tables throughput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

[Amazon's doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) has nothing to say about this which makes me nervous.

It explains how partitions are created when I increase throughput and size, but what happens when I reduce throughput and size? Do I scale up and have a bunch of partitions and then scale down and STILL have a bunch of partitions?

This would be really bad because if I scale up a lot and then scale way down I would have many partitions sharing my read/write capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as you thought. nothing happens.
When reducing throughput, nothing happen to dynamodb partitions.
If you get a situation were a bunch of partition created, the only way to "decrease" them back, is to do migration (create new table and copy data)

Comment: yup reading about this now. wtf amazon thanks for not mentioning this!!

Answer (score 0):

Points to note while reducing the Throughput,

- It will reduce the RCU/WCU per partition also
- This might result in Throttling, even when capacity used is lesser than table's provisioned capacity.

The illustration & solution is explained [here](https://hackernoon.com/beware-of-dilution-of-dynamodb-throughput-due-to-excessive-scaling-4df51063edae)